# Multiple hibernate @Id annotations on base and subclass

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot (1.5.2.RELEASE) with hibernate-core (5.2.9.Final)

I have two classes (getters,setters,constructors are omitted) and appropriate tables in DB (USERS table with 3 columns and USERS_HISTORY with 6 columns)

```
  public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
  }

  public class UserHistory extends User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long hstId;
    private Instant hstTimestamp;
    private String changedBy;
  }
```

How can I annotate both User.id and UserHistory.hstId with @Id annotation?

I can't annotate only User.id because one user can have multiple rows in history table.

When I call userRepository.findOne(Long id) I want to select User row with User.id, and when I call userHistoryRepository.findOne(Long hstId) I want to select UserHistory row with UserHistory.hstId.

UserHistoryRepository and UserRepository both extends Spring Data JPA CrudRepository.

My current solution is based on three classes, but I am trying to find solution based only on two classes.

My current solution looks like this:

```
  public class UserBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
  }

  public class User extends UserBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    Long id;
  }

  public class UserHistory extends UserBase implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long hstId;
    private Instant hstTimestamp;
    private String changedBy;
    private Long id;

    //constructor sets this.id = User.id
    public UserHistory(Long hstId, Instant hstTimestamp, String changedBy, User user) {
      //other lines omitted
      this.id = user.id;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `UserHistory` should not extends `User`.

Use [One to Many](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) relationship  because one user can have multiple rows in history table

Comment: Hi,UserHistory MUST extend User. I am using UserHistory object and corresponding table as audit table, something similar to Envers in Hibernate, but a lot more readable (to get all user history i can call select * from USERS_HISTORY where id = user.id). Like that i can see every change that was made on certain User object.

Comment: Just trust me, all what you need is one-to-many relationships